# Custom "list" view

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, a `List` will automatically format the sub views you pass it, so something like this:

```swift
List {
  Text("A")
  Text("B")
}
```

Will result in both text views being correctly placed, with separators between them etc...

Additionally, it is also possible to mix static and dynamically generated data, like this:

```swift
List {
  Text("A")
  ForEach(foo) { fooElement in CustomView(fooElement) }
  Text("B")
  ForEach(bar) { barElement in CustomView(barElement) }
}
```

My goal is to write my own custom type that would allow this kind of use by its users (ie: a view that lets the users provide views using the new function builder DSL, without requiring them to write their own modifiers to place them on the screen), but I don't know at all what to put in the initialiser of my custom view.

The native SwiftUI views are making use of `@ViewBuilder` and receive a generic type conforming to `View`, but the way they are able to extract elements (from, say, a `ForEach` view) is mysterious and I'm pretty sure it's not even possible.

Maybe I missed something, so I'm curious to know your opinion about this?

EDIT:
An example might be clearer. Many of you must have seen the nice examples online with cards arranged on top of each other using a `ZSack`, so what if I want to create a `CardStack` type that would allow my users to write code like this?

```swift
CardStack {
  SomeView()
  AnotherView()
  ForEach(1...10) { i in
    NumberView(i)
  }
}
```

This would result in 12 cards stacked on top of each other, note that the types are not homogenous and that we used `ForEach`.

Comment: Have you read and understood the Function Builders feature? https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9992cf3c11c2d5e0ea20bee98657d93902d5b174/proposals/XXXX-function-builders.md

Comment: @Alexander Indeed, but I don't believe this would enable me to do this due to some SwiftUI limitations. Do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: Nope, just trying to gauge the "current state". So what exactly do you mean by "but the way they are able to extract elements (from, say, a ForEach view) is mysterious and I'm pretty sure it's not even possible." and "some SwiftUI limitations"?

Comment: About extracting elements : When a native SwiftUI View is initialised, all it knows is that it's content is of a type `T` that conforms to the View protocol. When a `List` is initialised, how does it even know how many elements it has been initialised with for instance?

Comment: I think `List` is built by [`ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder). The compiler transforms every line within the List closure's body into a method call on `ViewBuilder`. These method calls are able to increment an internal counter that's incremented with every line.

Comment: @Alexander `ViewBuilder` indeed aggregates views, but the type it returns and gives to `List` (and all other views that use `ViewBuilder`) has no accessible *public* property to determine the internal view graph, hence apparently no way to implement something like list with the public API only.

Comment: I don't understand why you need access into the internal structure of a List. From what I can tell, you just need to be able to create a `List`. Your `CardStackBuilder` should have full knowledge of the views provided to it, which it can forward into a (explicitly invoked) ViewBuilder to produce a `List` with the structure you're looking for

Comment: @Alexander If I implement a `CardStackBuilder`, the issue I'll have is what I mentioned about `ForEach`: how would I extract each view produced by `ForEach`? The goal being to enable code such as `CardStack { FooView(); ForEach(1...10) { Text("\(i)") ; BarView() }`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196393/discussion-between-alexander-and-trevor).

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your challenge is figuring out ViewBuilder. As for the flow of data from children to ancestors, please read on:

By using preferences (check my article https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/), you can make information flow from children to ancestors.

Once you fully understand preferences and get them to work, you can try making the implementation more clean and transparent, so that the end user of your Stack doesn't even realize he is using preferences. To do so, you could use some View extensions. The final code could look something like this:

```swift
CardStack {
   SomeView().card(title: "", border: .red)
   AnotherView().card(title: "", border: .green)

  ForEach(items) { item in
    NumberView(item).card(item.name, border: .blue)
  }
}
```

And your `.card()` implementation may be something like this:

```swift
extension View {
   func card(title: String, border: Color) -> CardCustomizer<Self> {
       return CardCustomizer(viewContent: self, title: title, border: border)
   }
}

struct CardCustomizer<Content: View>: View {
    public let viewContent: Content
    public let title: String
    public let border: Color

    var body: some View {
        viewContent.preference(MyCardPref.self, value: ...)
    }
}
```

**I think it is best if you try first to make it work without the View extensions, so you get one thing right. Then proceed to encapsulate the preference logic with extensions. Otherwise there are too many new things to deal with.**