# How to use GeometryReader to achieve a table like layout?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to achieve a layout like this:
[image: A table with two rows and three columns]

For this simple example the base would be something like this:

```swift
HStack {
  VStack {
    Text("Foo")
    Text("W")
    Text("X")
  }
  VStack {
    Text("Bar")
    Text("Y")
    Text("Z")
  }
}
```

Now that `relativeSize(...)` is deprecated, the only remaining option I see is `GeometryReader`, but the issue with it is that once it's itself nested in another stack, it will attempt to fill all available space, in other terms it cannot determine the size it's containing stack would have had if it wasn't present in it and I end up with an overly sized stack.

I wonder if I'm missing something or if this is just how stacks work, or maybe a beta bug?

Thank you for your help

EDIT:
I did this:

```swift
VStack {
GeometryReader { /* @kontiki code */ }
Text("Other")
Spacer().layoutPriority(1)
}
```

But unfortunately this is the result I get, do you think this is a SwiftUI bug?
[image]

Comment: Two things. First, your root stack is an `HStack` with 2 `VStacks` inside of it - that means you'll have two columns. Each `VStack` has 3 `Texts` in it, meaning 3 rows. But your image is the opposite. Also, consider that a stack is inherently centered, and you may well *not* have a "grid-like" appearance without modifiers. Second, check out my edited answer for how to use a `GeometryReader` to get the size of the root `HStack`, applying a `frame` modifier to your texts. It *might* work - remember stacks are very "fluid" and unmodified texts are *only* the size of the actual text.

Comment: @dfd oops sorry, typed quickly the example and I mixed them

Comment: @dfd I see no answer from you

Comment: That's why I commented instead. Not to sound harsh, but I'm not doing your work. @kontiki is very awesome (he's helped me a few time in the last month). This isn't a competition. My earlier comment - since deleted or never done - was an answer where, now deprecated - my accepted answer (twice upvoted since) relied on `relativeHeight`. Again, this isn't a competition, and if my pointing out something I found critical to an answer (2x3 versus 3x2 along with how stacks work) isn't working for you, apologies. I'm notingthe answer from @kontiki is **much** more elegant that anything I could do.

Comment: In "Second, check out my edited answer for how to use " I thought you were referring to something? I don't understand what you mean by "I'm not doing your work".

Comment: My bad. I did post an answer on a different question (which didn't link to) and misunderstood your comment. I sincerely apologize. The answer below is perfect.

Comment: @dfd No problem! I'll look at your answer! :)

Comment: No need. It was based on how @kontiki shows to use `GeometryReader`. He worked with me on something that doesn't apply here, and based on the editing of the answer, I'm sure it's well beyond where I'm at with everything Apple introduced last month. (as for preferences? Yep, check the blog!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Second Attempt**

I think this does exactly what you need. It uses Preferences. If you need to learn more about how to use SwiftUI preferences, check this [post](https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/) I wrote. They are fully explained there, but it is too long of a subject to post it here.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyPref: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat

    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0

    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct SetWidthPreference: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Rectangle().fill(Color.clear).preference(key: MyPref.self, value: proxy.size.width)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var width: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Foo")
                        Text("Bar")
                    }.frame(width: width * 0.7, alignment: .leading).fixedSize().border(Color.red)

                    VStack {
                        Text("W")
                        Text("Y")
                    }.frame(width: width * 0.15).fixedSize().border(Color.red)

                    VStack {
                        Text("X")
                        Text("Z")
                    }.frame(width: width * 0.15).fixedSize().border(Color.red)
                }

                Text("Text below table")

            }
            .border(Color.green, width: 3)

            HStack { Spacer() }.background(SetWidthPreference())
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(MyPref.self) { w in
            print("\(w)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.width = w
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Previous Attempt (I keep it here, so comments make sense)**

This example will draw 3 columns with 0.7, 0.15 and 0.15 of the parent's width. It's a starting point that you can fine tune. Note that the borders are there so that you can see what you are doing, of course you can remove them.

If GeometryReader is expanding too much, explain exactly what is that you want to accomplish, providing more context on the surroundings of the table (i.e., GeometryReader).

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { proxy in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Foo")
                    Text("Bar")
                }.frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.7, alignment: .leading).fixedSize().border(Color.red)

                VStack {
                    Text("W")
                    Text("Y")
                }.frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.15).fixedSize().border(Color.red)

                VStack {
                    Text("X")
                    Text("Z")
                }.frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.15).fixedSize().border(Color.red)
            }
        }.padding(20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the GeometryReader is itself in another VStack, and it will itself inside of a scroll view

Comment: No problem. But you are leaving too many unknowns. Maybe it is clear to you, but not to us. You mention relativeSize(), so I assumed you wanted to have relative size columns (hence my answer). Now you are saying the table is inside a VStack, but VStacks grow to accommodate their contents, they do not have (unless you force it) a set width. So if you are going to put a table inside it, the table needs to determine its size. Should the table grow as much as possible?, have a fixed width? shrink as much as possible? Try to describe a concrete example and what are your layout expectations.

Comment: Sorry, indeed the way I thought I'd use it is a little contradictory, but now that I think about it, I realise that what I would need would be to get the GeometryReader to only read one axis, in other terms, I set the width of the containing stack, but I want it to select itself it's height (in other terms, I want it to grow depending on it's contents, but only on the vertical axis). Do you know of a way to do this? AFAICT, GeometryReader will automatically read in both axis, and expand in both axes unless a specific frame size is set.

Comment: You can try putting a spacer bellow the GeometryReader to make it compress vertically. You may also need to use .layoutPriority() to make the spacer take more priority than the GeometryReader. I did not try it, but in theory sounds good. I bet it will not be so easy though ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try it and update with the results.

Comment: I updated my question with the code I tried and the result, I don't understand why it behaves this way :/

Comment: Apparently, the GeometryReader gets pushed as we wanted. Unfortunately, it does so until it is zero in height, because its contents does not prevent it. I'll think another way and post back if I find any.

Comment: Ok, I think this is it. The new approach handles all your requirements. You mentioned that you were using a ScrollView, so I added that too. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! That's really interesting, I'll take time to read your article.

Comment: Started reading your articles, they are really great! I'll have to take more time to understand it all but that's really interesting and even makes me wonder if that wouldn't be part of the solution to this issue I encountered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57010729/custom-list-view.

Comment: I found a potential issue with the solution. When rotating the device multiple times, the `HStack { Spacer() }` never shrinks back (probably a bug in ScrollView). I think you can solve it by monitoring the device rotation and destroying and recreating the `HStack  { Spacer() }` view. I do not have time right now to test it, but seems possible. I posted some comments to your other question.

Comment: Thank you, finally had time to test your code, apart from the rotation issue I also noticed that if the content based on the "read size" happens to make the container larger (eg: if the total equals to more than 100% of the size) the app will go in an infinite loop where it constantly makes everything larger. It's totally understandable but it would definitely be safer if there was something to prevent this. I'll try to find one and update if I do.

Comment: In case you want to have a look, I did an experimentation: https://github.com/adtrevor/OneAxisGeometryReader

Comment: Nice! You're addressing what I call "GeometryReader's chicken or the egg problem", what came first: the parent or its children ;-)